# Usage of the word entropy in the context of this question

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Could someone define the word entropy for me in the context below.

"I have journeyed through the darkness between the most distant stars. I have beheld the births of negative-suns and borne witness to the entropy of entire realities..."

Source: http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Zeratul

Comment: It's an informational term, meaning 'the reason why order doesn't emerge from chaos'; e.g, your desk or your house won't get clean by waiting for a random physical event, like tossing up all the papers and having them fall into neat stacks. This is theoretically possible, but so unlikely that it just doesn't occur. The fact that it doesn't is the law of entropy. "Nothing will come of nothing", as Bateson puts it. To defeat entropy temporarily, information must be added to the system; there is no way to defeat it permanently, as the Laws of Thermodynamics attest.

Comment: Bearing witness to the entropy of an entire reality suggests omniscience, and over a very long period of time.

Comment: Have you considered the definition of *entropy* in various dictionaries?

Comment: in this case it simply means "decay".  it s inconceivable the writer actually understands the mathematics of entropy; they're just using it to roughly mean "decay".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entropy is the gradual decline into disorder, it is the likelihood that a system will descend into chaos. Full definition [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/entropy).

Comment: So the word entropy is synomic to 'the measurement of chaos'?

Comment: Hmm.. I think it is more accurate to say it is the measurement of **how fast it declines into chaos**

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy

Comment: Julian, which chaos are you measuring? Ordered chaos or disordered chaos?

Comment: "the measurement of chaos" - to some extent. it's a subtle and complex mathematical / cosmological concept.  there's no point trying to ask what is the "real" meaning (read a text book on it if you want that). in every day usage as Zen mentions it is simply used to mean **the gradual decline into disorder**.  In mathematics it can mean the "measure" of (something complicated) but that sense is either **not used**, or just used very badly/loosely in common conversation, ad slogans etc.